# Filtering a NSOutlineView/NSTreeController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsoutlineview

How would I use a search box to filter a NSOutlineView/NSTreeController? I know it would have something to do with bindings and a predicate. But not specificaly how to. Could someone take me through the steps of filtering an NSOutlineView/NSTreeController?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can. NSArrayController allows you to give it a filter predicate; NSTreeController doesn't. I suggest you [file a bug](https://bugreport.apple.com/).

Comment: Could I filter the NSArrayController the NSTreeController is connected to, but would it display the results in the NSOutlineView?

Comment: Just tried to file a bug but I just get an error when I log in, shows how good apples bug reporter is. http://snapplr.com/q3ns

Comment: My guess is that filtering the array controller would only filter the root objects, not any descendant objects. I haven't tried it, but I can't see how it could work.

Comment: As for the bug reporter: Do you have an ADC account? You need one.

Comment: It works but only with the root objects is there any way to expand it to search the decendant objects?

Comment: Yes, i do have an ADC account.

Comment: So, Is there any way to make it search the decendant objects?

Comment: SO THERE IS NO WAY AT ALL TO FILTER THE DESCENDANT OBJECTS?

Comment: You can most likely implement a subclass of NSTreeController that does the filtering. Would require some effort though that's for sure.

Comment: @PeterHosey quick question, is there a way to filter a NSOutlineView without using a NSTreeController?

Comment: @Jai: You should ask that as a separate question.

Comment: This answer is no longer valid. See the `fetchPredicate` property.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen: Does that work for NSTreeControllers, though? The documentation doesn't say. Also, it's specific to Core Data, and the author of this question didn't say he was using Core Data.

Comment: I found a nifty way for this, combining the other answer with the `PredicateOutlineNode` class and a tricky way to identify which nodes are used by the NSCellViews, all in this project: https://github.com/tempelmann/SSDP-Browser/

Answer (score 1):

As of macOS 10.11, `NSTableView` (and therefore the subclass `NSOutlineView`) has new `hideRows` & `unhideRows` methods that simplify the task to filtering out rows. There's still no automatic support for filtering out items in `NSTreeController` (which is *not* a subclass of `NSArrayController`, and thus does not inherit its `filter` predicate), but it at least does a lot of the heavy lifting of allowing you to keep the whole model in the controller while only displaying only a subset of it.

Answer (score 1):

I wrecked my brain for quite a bit on this one, but its actually remarkably simple to live filter an `NSTreeController`, you just have to adapt your actual node object.

In my case I gave up on implementing the actual filter on the controller and just passed a predicate down my tree nodes. When the predicate doesn't match on a leaf node, I simply removes it from the children array.

```
class PredicateOutlineNode: NSObject {

    typealias Element = PredicateOutlineNode

    @objc dynamic var children: [Element] = [] {
        didSet {
            propagatePredicatesAndRefilterChildren()
        }
    }

    @objc private(set) dynamic var filteredChildren: [Element] = [] {
        didSet {
            count = filteredChildren.count
            isLeaf = filteredChildren.isEmpty
        }
    }

    @objc private(set) dynamic var count: Int = 0
    @objc private(set) dynamic var isLeaf: Bool = true

    var predicate: NSPredicate? {
        didSet {
            propagatePredicatesAndRefilterChildren()
        }
    }

    private func propagatePredicatesAndRefilterChildren() {
        // Propagate the predicate down the child nodes in case either
        // the predicate or the children array changed.
        children.forEach { $0.predicate = predicate }

        // Determine the matching leaf nodes.
        let newChildren: [Element]

        if let predicate = predicate {
            newChildren = children.compactMap { child -> Element? in
                if child.isLeaf, !predicate.evaluate(with: child) {
                    return nil
                }
                return child
            }
        } else {
            newChildren = children
        }

        // Only actually update the children if the count varies.
        if newChildren.count != filteredChildren.count {
            filteredChildren = newChildren
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can set your `NSTreeController` class name to `PredicateOutlineNode` and its key paths to `filteredChildren`, `count` and `isLeaf`. You can name your object accessors differently of course. Now when I want to filter the tree, I set an `NSPredicate` on the root node, which passes it down.

Also works with KVO, no additional code required, the `NSOutlineView` will update automatically.

Comment: It mostly works, though for finding both deep leaf elements as well as matching interim nodes I had to change `child.isLeaf,` into `child.count == 0 &&`.

Comment: For anyone wanting to see this in action, I've published a fairly compact open source program that uses an NSOutlineView with Bindings and an NSSearchField to filter the results: https://github.com/tempelmann/SSDP-Browser/